# What is ContextWrapper in Android?

Tags: android

This is what the documentation for ContextWrapper states:

> Proxying implementation of Context that simply delegates all of its
> calls to another Context. Can be subclassed to modify behavior without
> changing the original Context.

I'm having a hard time understanding this, does it just implement methods of Context in another class?

Comment: Probably a better question is why do you think you need this class? Its kind of a very special usecase, usually not dealt with by normal applications.

Comment: I was actually following a tutorial where they extended a class with ContextWrapper, so I'm assuming it gives Context access or functionality in the class?

Comment: Couldn't that also be achieved by passing in Context to your class?

Comment: I would assume so. I'm just wondering why would someone use ContextWrapper?

Comment: One common usecase for it is to override the theme of a dialog by passing in a pre-configured contextwrapper.. but liike I said, its a rare condition and primarily a function of core android platform, not normal applications :)

Comment: Was I right in my assumption? It gives Context access or functionality in a class?

Answer (score 1):

This is an incredibly powerful capability. It does exactly what AtomaticallyBeyond writes, that is, it simply delegates method calls to another Context.  So, you might say, big deal! But if you write another class that that extends ContextWrapper, that class can override the some of the method of the delegate context. For example, getAssets or getResources.  Most applications have no need to do that, but for some more sophisticated applications, I go back to my first comment, that's an incredible powerful capability.