# What is ContextWrapper in android

Tags: android, android-context

I referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66308445/what-is-contextwrapper-in-android) but has no answers.

The documentation also hasn't made it clear.

Can someone provide a clear explanation?

Comment: What are you confused about in the documentation? It seems to explain it well as far as I was concerned.

Comment: @HenryTwist I can't understand the documentation clearly. Can you give an explanation with an easy example?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says, it takes in a base `Context` instance and behaves as a `Context` itself, just by delegating all calls through the base context.

The difference comes when you inherit from the `ContextWrapper` and override some of its functionality, for example you could override the `Context.getTheme()` method to provide a different theme for your new context. Then the `ContextWrapper` would behave identically to the base context except for exposing an alternative theme.

It's generally used internally and not for non-system apps so you probably would never have to deal with it.

---

Note that the example I gave of overriding a theme can be better seen if you take a look at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.java) of `ContextThemeWrapper`, which acts as a convenience class for providing an alternative theme. This demonstrates a use-case for it quite nicely.

Comment: Is this related to wrapper classes in java?

Comment: No, Java wrapper classes are used to wrap primitives to be used as objects.